# How to search for a variable in Robot Framework using RIDE?

Tags: python, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotframework

I am using RIDE and looking for a variable e.g. ${customer_email} . I only see Search option for Keyword,Tests and Tag. Any idea how to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to search for a variable in RIDE, however you can use the keyword `Log Variables` that will provide you with all variables in the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

it would be very good if in RIDE user is able to search variables in resource files. unfortunately it's impossible for now.

Comment: This should be a comment.